# incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[128]' to parameter of type 'char **'

Tags: c

I can't figure out why does the following code generates this error:

`incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[128]' to parameter of type 'char **'`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv) 
{
    char line[128];
    size_t n;

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (NULL == fp)
    {
        log_error("%d. %s", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(-1 != getline(&line, &n, fp))
    {
        // do something
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error is generated by the following line `-1 != getline(&line, &n, fp)` Here is the prototype for `getline,`

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `argv` argument is of the wrong type.

Comment: [Read the `getline()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html):  "The application shall ensure that `*lineptr` is a valid argument that could be passed to the `free()` function.".  Your code is a `SIGSEGV` waiting to happen.

Comment: As for the error, you're supposed to pass a pointer to a pointer variable (that is either pointing to some dynamically allocated memory, or is initialized to `NULL`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getline` will allocate a buffer for you (that you should free when you are finished with it).  Instead of passing it a pointer to a statically allocated buffer, just pass it a pointer to a `char *`.  If the pointer is NULL, it'll allocate a new buffer and point you to it.  Changing `char line[128];` to `char *line = NULL;` should do the trick; just remember to free it when you're done with it.

From the man page:

> If *lineptr is NULL, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line, which should be freed by the user program.  (In this case, the value in *n is ignored.)
>
> Alternatively,  before  calling  getline(), *lineptr can contain a pointer to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size.  If the buffer is not large enough to hold the line, getline() resizes it with realloc(3), updating
>          *lineptr and *n as necessary.
>
> In either case, on a successful call, *lineptr and *n will be updated to reflect the buffer address and allocated size respectively.

How it might look in your example `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t n;

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (NULL == fp)
    {
        log_error("%d. %s", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(-1 != getline(&line, &n, fp))
    {
        // do something
    }
    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```